# Regex: ignore character on several different positions

Tags: regex, perl

Given this string: `W1_R23_4_56_78`

Searched is: R2345678 (in one match)
all from the 4th position without any _

```
^.{3}\K.[^_]*
```

gives `R23`

Is it possible to get one match or is it done by substitution or ...

Thanks in advance to guiding the right direction

Comment: Right now you get a single result, what do you mean by "Is it possible to get one match" What is the expected result?

Comment: @Thefourthbird The expected result is given as `R2345678`

Comment: Remove the first 3 characters, then do `s/_//g` to remove all the `_` characters.

Comment: @Barmar That what not very clear to me, but now that you say it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to capture all after position 3, without underscores, and join into a wanted string

```
my $str = 'W1_R23_4_56_78';

pos $str = 3;

my $res = join '', $str =~ /[^_]+/g;
```

That [pos](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos) allows to change offset for the next search, see docs.  Note that this affects some future operations (do see the docs).

The following matching is in the list context, imposed by `join`, so the matches are returned.  (In patterns that match more than what we want we'd need to have the capturing parenthesis for the wanted parts so that only those are returned.)

Comment: Using `substr( $str, 3 ) =~ /[^_]+/g` would be less obscure than setting `pos( $str )`.

Comment: Re "*Note that this affects some future operations*", It'll affect the subsequent //g, but not beyond.

Comment: @ikegami I wanted to offer a way which doesn't change the original string (their purpose and context isn't stated), and wanted specifically to introduce `pos`. The `substr` way is good, no question :).  As for what `pos` changes I want to suggest that one reads the docs...

Comment: `substr( $str, 3 )` doesn't change the original string. The fact that many would have to read up on `pos` is the very reason it's a not a great choice.

Comment: "_substr( $str, 3 ) doesn't change the original string._" -- well, yes ... it's a good way to extract the target for the following operation.  I wanted to introduce `pos`.

Answer (score 2):

```perl
my $x = "W1_R23_4_56_78" =~ s/^[^_]+|_//gr;
```

The above removes up to (and including) the first `_`. If you really want to remove three positions, you can use

```perl
my $x = "W1_R23_4_56_78" =~ s/^.{3}|_//sgr;
```

or

```perl
my $x = substr( "W1_R23_4_56_78", 3 ) =~ s/_//gr;
```

Comment: You probably meant `^...` as the OP mentions "all form the 4th position".

Comment: @choroba, Given that the three characters to skip are `W1_`, I believe they actually want to skip the bit before `_`. I suppose I could provide both solutions rather than make an assumption

Answer (score 1):

In your question you state:

> Searched is: R2345678 (in one match) all from the 4th position without any _

But your pattern `^.{3}\K.[^_]*` uses a dot on the 4th position, which can also match an underscore.

So in this example string `W1__` it will match the last underscore.

---

If you want a match after at least 3 characters, you could skip the first 3 characters using `(*SKIP)(*F)` instead of using `\K` and then match all other characters except for an underscore or a newline.

```
^.{1,3}(*SKIP)(*F)|[^_\r\n]+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X1r7l0/1).

Then join the result:

```
my $str = 'W1_R23_4_56_78';
my $result = join '', $str =~ /^.{1,3}(*SKIP)(*F)|[^_\r\n]+/g;
print($result);
```

Output

```
R2345678
```

Answer (score 0):

No substitutions, joining, global matching / re-entrancy.
Nothing needed but a single pass, simple match.

```
'W1_R23_4_56_78' =~ /^.{3}(R\d+)(?{$res=$^N})(?:_*(\d+)(?{$res.=$^N}))+/;
print $res;
```

output

```
R2345678
```